# API для постинга товаров в магазин Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Где найти API по размещению товаров в магазин через API со своего сайта? Так как это делает Shopify.

Comment: Здравствуйте.Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен другим участникам [**StackOverflow на русском**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com). Добавьте ссылки и примеры, свои разработки в данной области. Используйте более конкретное описание ваше проблематики.

Comment: Так а как по другому написать и привести примеры кода, если я даже не могу такого апи найти? Это реализовано на shopify.com. Но в фейсбуке нет упоминания по постингу товаров со своего сайта в магазин фейсбука.

Comment: Нужно Ваш вопрос подкрепить хотя бы скрином и более точным описанием. Иначе, на вопрос может быть дан неоднозначный вопрос, который может породить дискуссии. Ссылки на сайт нужно указывать с их подкреплением, иначе, если сайт сменит политику работы, вопрос потеряет актуальность и может быть трактован неверно. Старайтесь избегать одних только ссылок на другие источники

Answer (score 0):

Раньше данная возможность была закрыта.

Щас уже есть открытое API.

Пробуйте:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-catalog/

Comment: можете ещё вот это прочитать: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access#limits